# Kubernetes persistent volume claim, size is not truly limited

Tags: kubernetes

I am using NFS persistent storage on my Kubernetes cluster and I'm trying to limit the size of storage a deployment can get.

Basically, I want to make sure that if a deployement uses a claim of 5 Gb, my container can't create more than 5Gb of files.

Any idea how I could create this constraint?

Comment: Hi, how come a container can exceed the capacity of the persistent volume ? If you request certain amount in PVC then it is bound to a pv which has  that amount of capacity.

Comment: you can use limit range and storage resource quota to bound a namespace with the certain number of pvc and total amount of storage in that namespace.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi If you create a pv and pvc of 5 Gb on an NFS storage with 200Gb available, the container can use up to 200Gb if it wants to ...

Limit range check the pv claim at creation time but not after

Answer (score 1):

Its up to the storage backend to force the quota/limit.
([Ref](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61641))

You may use `nfs-provisioner` volume plugin to enable per-volume quota on NFS persistent volumes. ([Ref](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/nfs/docs/deployment.md))

Comment: That's actually what i'm using, and there is no such things as storage size check at runtime :/

Comment: or maybe i missed something ?

Comment: @Seb , I'm not so sure about , but below comment in (https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/blob/master/nfs/docs/deployment.md) is the relevant one to get the quota working `You may also want to enable per-PV quota enforcement. It is based on xfs project level quotas and so requires that the volume mounted at /export be xfs mounted with the prjquota/pquota option. It also requires that it has the privilege to run xfs_quota`